# Basic loop ends unexpectedly

Tags: c

I was playing with the basic sintax of C and I came up with the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1000;
    int b = 0;
    while (a > b) {
        a++;
        b++;
    }
    puts("Loop ended");
}
```

Incredibly this programme outputs `Loop ended` even if `a` will always be bigger than `b` no matter how much I increment them: I mean 1001 > 1 is as True as 2481298241 > 2481297241.

Please explain me what is the cause of such a weird behaviour.

Comment: Nehavior is not well defined once the a overlaps.

Comment: Compile it for 64-bit.  Post again when it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are facing is [Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

> In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic
>   operation attempts to create a numeric value that is too large to be
>   represented within the available storage space.

It was just a matter of chance though cause its UB when overflow happens.

> Since an arithmetic operation may produce a result larger than the
>   maximum representable value, a potential error condition may result.
>   In the C programming language, signed integer overflow causes
>   undefined behavior, while unsigned integer overflow causes the number
>   to be reduced modulo a power of two, meaning that unsigned integers
>   "wrap around" on overflow. This "wrap around" is the cause of the
>   famous "Split Screen" in Pac-Man.[2] A "wrap around" corresponds to
>   the fact, that e.g. if the addition of two positive integers produces
>   an overflow, it may result in an unexpected result. For example with
>   unsigned 32 bit integers, 4000000000u + 1000000000u = 705032704u.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - I believe that is what the article on Wiki says above.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR answer: in your case, There is no check on the value of `a`. So, the increment operation will make `int a` value to overflow at a certain point of time. The result of overflow of a `signed` data type [as used in your code] is undefined. In this case, it is making `a>b` to evaluate to false.

Note: However, in case of *unsigned* data type,

> computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.

Comment: When `a` overflows its value is undefined.

Comment: `the behaviour is then undefined [maybe implementation dependent]` - How do such answers get such high votes?

Comment: @al-Acme well, to clarify, for signed data type, the result of overflow is undefined behaviour, as you're mentioned in your answer. Maybe some implementation provide a feature to _wrap_ the value keeping the maximum value present in the variable.

Comment: @SouravGhosh : I do not know what `maybe` means here.

Comment: @al-Acme OK, removed the controversial part. Does it make the answer better? Please review.

Answer (score 3):

This is a representation error, eventually a will overflow the int container and will be less than B.Think of it like an car odometer, it will eventually say 0 but that doesn't mean that you have a brand new engine :)

Answer (score 1):

Overflow. A cistern in a lav can only hold so such, then stils. then the water on the floor equals

PS: This is a metaphor

Answer (score 0):

It's as all other answers pointed out, the integer overflow problem, try to check that indeed it is with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXINTEGER 2147483647

int main() 
{
    int a = 1000;
    int b = 0;

    while (a > b) 
    {
        a++;
        b++;
        if (a == 2147483647)
        {
            puts("a reached it's maximum value, exiting");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    puts("Loop ended");
    return 0;
}
```

the maximum signed 32 bit integer value is `2147483647`.